# Can't Pass bashrc defined arguments to the terminal

Tags: python, c++, bash

I am trying to write a code that automate some of Nasa's Heasoft program - this doesn't matter -,

heainit is definied in the bashrc as:

```
export HEADAS=~/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31
alias heainit='. $HEADAS/headas-init.sh
```

so whenever I write heainit on terminal it works pretty fine. However, whenever I tried to pass "heainit" to the terminal through c++ or Python, the code it self works but it doesn't initiate the program!

Ik that alise doesn't create an actual path there but i tried every possibility ik about.

in c++ I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv){ string ind, outd;
const char* heainit = "/home/karim/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/headas-init.sh" ; 
system(heainit);
return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(string, char*){
 string ind, outd;
 std::string HEADAS = "/home/karim/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31";
 std::string str = std::string(". //") + HEADAS + std::string("/headas-init.sh");
 const char *c = str.c_str(". /home/karim/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31/heafas-init.sh");
 system(const char* c);
 return 0;
 }
```

in python I tried:

```
import os
import subprocess
os.system("heainit")
subprocess.run("heainit",capture_output=True)
```

and

```
HEADAS=~/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31
heainit="." + "\t" + HEADAS + "/headas-init.sh"
subprocess.run(heainit, shell=True)
```

My latest attempt was to write a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export HEADAS=~/heasoft-6.27.2/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-libc2.31
export HEADAS
alias heainit='. $HEADAS/headas-init.sh'
heainit
```

and the prompt gives the following: `./hea.sh: line 6: heainit: command not found`

whenever I execute any of the aforementioned codes with anyother command like "ls -l" for instance it works perfectly :")) I don't know how should I pass this argument(it should be followed by others when the program is initiated) to the terminal yet and I don't know what i lack to go. Maybe the problem is trivial but i'm stuck there for a long time now.

Comment: Do you understand what `.` does in shell? What would be the point of sourcing a script from a `system()` call? Why would you want to do that? It has no effect on current process anyway.

Comment: What is the content of the file? Is it only setting environment variables or actually creating some side effects?

Comment: As far as ik . do run or open a file through the shell.

Comment: runing the file initiates a program that do temporal analysis to data collected beforehand, but it takes time or argument manually and this is so time consuming for nearly 113,000 time events. Thus i want to automate this process via python or c++ but it still requires initiating the program first.

Answer (score 0):

> whenever I tried to pass "heainit" to the terminal through c++ or Python, the code it self works but it doesn't initiate the program!

`heainit` is an `alias`. So first: the `system` call runs the shell in non-interactive mode in which `alias` is ignored and secondly: most probably you have an `if [[ $- ~= *i* ]]` on top of your bashrc to return when the shell is not interactive. In short: an `alias` is not a command and is meant to be run only in an interactive shell. [bash shell manual aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases)

If you wish to run `heainit` from the terminal, you could create an executable in `PATH`. Or you could create a function and add it to `/etc/bash.bashrc` before the interactive check or like to `/etc/profile.d/*`.

Still, that would most probably solve nothing, as the file is sourced. `system()` call and `subprocess()` runs a subprocess, the subprocess environment doesn't affect the parent environment. So if this assessment is true, sourcing the file is doing effectively nothing as it sources it in subprocess which doesn't affect the current environment. The solution would be to write a parser of the file (either a full blown shell parser and interpreter or something simpler depending on the content of the file) and parse the text from the file inside the current process.